# MobX 4 `decorate` doesnt work with `computed`

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

**EDIT: this is now solved and i no longer need help. see solution below. thank you**

I am getting a weird error when trying the new `decorate` syntax with `computed` variables - any idea why it might sometimes invalidate the store? I'm pretty sure the `computed` is causing this as it works when I remove it.

sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jnmz0v2189

and screenshot here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i should use `decorate` on  the class, not the instance.

https://twitter.com/askerovlab/status/974752575676436481

more info here.